# Validating a Django field dependently on context

Tags: django, forms, validation

I write the code to edit the list of users which belong to a team. For this I create a form, as below:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, verbose_name=_("Name"), help_text=_('Organization Name'), max_length=256)

class Team(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization')
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, verbose_name=_("Name"), help_text=_('Team Name'), max_length=256)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='teams')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TeamUsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['users']

    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(request.user.organization), required=False)

    def clean_users(self):
        users = self.cleaned_data['users']
        if users.exclude(organization=request.user.organization):
            raise ValidationError(_("Cannot add user from another organization"))
        return users
```

The code above should look into `request` value to determine the current organization and restrict display and model store only to users from the same organization.

But the above code cannot work, because the value of `request` is not known at class loading time.

What do you suggest to do?

I thought of two variants:

1. create a local (to a function) class like the above class `TeamUsersForm`
2. dismiss using Django forms for this altogether and use more low-level API

Comment: Did the below answer worked for you?

Comment: @nik_m yes, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overide the `__init__` of the `TeamUsersForm` and access `request` there.

```
class TeamUsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['users'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(self.request.user.organization), required=False)
```

This implies that when you instantiate your form, you should it this way:

```
# somewhere in your views.py, probably

f = TeamUsersForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

Comment: I thought of this, but the field `users` of `TeamUsersForm` is initialized outside `__init__()`. So I doubt if your code will work